Connecting and printing with Zebra Printers in Ext Js
I'm currently developing an app in ExtJs where I am supposed to take a PDF and print it to the label.
The PDF is just a regular label for warehouse stuff so it's very basic. The app will be used by zebra smartphones and they'll be connected to the printers through bluetooth signals.
Does anyone has ever used Zebra's APIs? Currently trying to implement the BrowserPrint library but with no luck. At least the library gets loaded correctly..
this is the function I am currently working on:
onPrintClick() {
        var selected_device;
        var devices = [];
        BrowserPrint.getDefaultDevice("printer", function(device) {
        
            //Add device to list of devices and to html select element
            selected_device = device;
            devices.push(device);
            Ext.Msg.alert(device.name ? device.name : 'Unknown Device');
                
            //Discover any other devices available to the application
            BrowserPrint.getLocalDevices(function(device_list) {
                for(var i = 0; i < device_list.length; i++) {
            var device = device_list[i];
            if(!selected_device || device.uid != selected_device.uid) {
                devices.push(device);
                                Ext.Msg.alert(device.name);
                         }
        }
    }, function(){alert("Error getting local devices")},"printer");
        }, function(error){
            alert(error);
        });
    }


To clarify I am not having results, I'm connecting with localhost to a zebra phone connected to a printer through bluetooth. However I do not see any device printed

Overall its is covered here:
PDF/postscript or HTML to ZPL(Zebra Printing Language) code

Cordova
I guess you are using Cordova. If so you should use a plugin like
this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@foodexplorer/cordova-zebra-printer


Javascript
Here are more information about JavaScript
Tutorial:
https://techdocs.zebra.com/enterprise-browser/1-7/tutorial/printing/

I do not want to harvest the currants for the first link, which should to the job. I added support for Cordova, which I use. The tutorial is still valid and the best place to start, if he does not know nothing about how to implement it. I thought Bergson already used the search. But - you are right - too keep everything complete I added it now. I

Both are interesting links. Thanks. Unfortunatley they send the blob to the server and receive the information there.
